# Show a short version

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data that comes from my database, although I want to only show a preview of it. Is there any way I can have the same long content but show the same thing, only shortened?

Comment: Why dont you post an example or the code you are using.?

Comment: WHat kind of "data" is it? What's the database structure? How is the data supposed to be "shortened"? How/Where do you want to shorten it, when querying the database or afterwards in your application? A "little" more detail here, please ^^

Comment: Sorry, I didnt relise you guys would have needed it. Its just a mysql fetch and to show a field with alot of content. For example the content is 100 words, Id like the script only to show the first sentence, paragraph..

Comment: @user2594383, add information to the Question itself -> [edit]

Comment: Come on, man, give us a code. Guys, don't minus him so much, he is quite new to SO...

Comment: This question has been answered below. I dont see why you's needed "code" when he was able to do it with out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to use [substr()](https://www.php.net/substr) function.

`echo substr($string,$start_pos,$end_pos);`

The above one will display the strings content from the starting position to the end position as specified as the arguments.

Example

```
$str = 'Example string';
if(strlen($str) > 5)
  echo substr($str,0,5).'....';//To show there is more content
else
  echo $str;
```

Ouptput

> Examp....

Comment: Glad that i could help you..:-) Mark it as correct answer...'

Comment: How, I dont see a button to do it

Comment: You can see a white tick mark on the left side of the answer.Click on that